# How to restore the environment variable in win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I trying to change the the environment variable PATH for the java and i deleted the old PATH due to which some function doesnot working.i have also tried to search on the net for this issue but i am not able to find any solution for win 8.1 ,
So can any body help me for this.

Comment: The solution that works for any supported version of Windows should work. What have you tried exactly, so we don't suggest, something you already tried.  Be sure to update your question

Comment: I have tried to set the path for jdk and accidentlly i the path and then i tried to copy the PATH from the cmd command but this not working.

Comment: What are you trying exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to use a System Restore Point to revert to the state before the change was made. However, if you've made many other changes since deleting the PATH Environment Variable, you might find other applications have been uninstalled.

The System Path is stored in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path*. If you're lucky, you have a backup of your *old* path in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\PATH*. Copy that value into *Notepad*; make any additions needed for Java, separating the addition with a semicolon, and paste it into the the *System*, *Advanced System Settings*, *Environment Variables* dialog for PATH (which is probably safer than pasting back into the Registry -- an extra or omitted backslash there can cause **serious** issues).

For future changes, you might wish to add a **USER** Environment Variable called *Path*, which provides additional locations for the system to search *without affecting the System Path*. This is stored in the Registry at *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\Path*, but should be modified using the *System* CPL as above. Both sets of Path locations are searched when resources are needed.